# VIM script on HTML page:  how to know if the cursor was understand javascript block or html tags?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to make a comment plugin , e.g when you press `/` for twice , it will replace the head of the line with , e.g `#`.

But for HTML page , it was different , since it contains both tags and javascript , I will need to surround the block with `/* */` for javascript blocks , but `<!-- -->` for tags , but how can I know if it's javascript block or just tags ? For now i'm merely judging this with `&filetype` variable , but that's not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a vim plugin called `TComment`. It's what you want.

You can view the source code: https://github.com/jmartindf/vim-tcomment